# Error 400 al hacer post en postman Node.js

Tags: nodejs, api, post, postman

Estoy obteniendo un error al probar mi método post en node.js usando Postman.

El JSON que estoy enviando es

```
{
    "nombre": "Calidad",
    "img": "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/illustration-quality-control_53876-17831.jpg",
    "embedReportId": "56f74e26",
    "groupId": "ca4c1ce3",
    "baseUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=",
    "filter": {
        "$schema": "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#advanced",
        "target": {
            "table": "SAP",
            "column": "CEBE"
        },
        "operator": "In",
        "values": [
            ""
        ]
    }
}
```

Mi método Post:

```
api.post('/reporte', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("entra")
  const {body} = req
  const nuevoReporte = new ReportesPowerBi(body)
  try {
    const reporteGuardado = await nuevoReporte.save()
    res.status(200).send({ OK: true, reporteGuardado })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send({ OK: false, error})
  }
})
```

El error que estoy obteniendo es el error 400, a continuacion muestro el error que me saca en Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era quitar el simbolo $ de schema aunque en el modelo lo tenga definidio de esa manera.

El JSON debe quedar así:

```
{
    "nombre": "Calidad",
    "img": "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/illustration-quality-control_53876-17831.jpg",
    "embedReportId": "56f74e26",
    "groupId": "ca4c1ce3",
    "baseUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=",
    "filter": {
        "schema": "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#advanced",
        "target": {
            "table": "SAP",
            "column": "CEBE"
        },
        "operator": "In",
        "values": [
            ""
        ]
    }
}
```